# Should I remove a question based on an incorrect premise?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28072/how-does-an-array-of-concrete-pillars-save-a-rocket) in response to some questions raised in an answer to [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28068/16008). In my research, I discovered that the original answer appears to be incorrect or only part of the story, making my question somewhat flawed and redundant.

**What should I do with my question if it becomes redundant due to developments in another?**

I see three options:

- Close as duplicate to help direct future queries to an answer.
- Delete the question entirely and post more information on the original (I've already done this)
- Leave the question as-is even though it's now hypothetical an essentially unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend first to not do anything yet. The answer in the other question continues to evolve. It's possible that "to the vehicle" shouldn't be in the first sentence, I don't see that in the linked answer itself, don't know what the original Russian says in the linked source there.

But if it ultimately turns out that these are there to protect the underground bunker, then this might evolve into a question about how the pillars might protect the underground bunker.

Deleting makes things *invisible* which deprives others the ability to see the text, and which could lead to someone else posting a question about bunker-protection. Leaving it there, perhaps on hold, allows people to know of its existence.

Hold is good because it will stop people from posting answers, which is a good thing if you are going to be adjusting the question. If that's what you decide, just leave a comment explaining this.

I've added another close vote for duplicate. If closed as such, it will recommend you re-edit the question, which might be exactly what you do once the first issue is resolved. One more vote will do it, and you can always vote to close your own question.

**edit:** I've just retracted my close vote. There is a new, [nice answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/28094/12102) that appears to be *the answer* to your question, and your premise does not seem far off any more (with the caveat that it's the other stuff that's protected, but not the vehicle).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in this case you are right to delete the question. You essentially have your answer (they aren't for the purpose the question is predicated on). In that case there is no reason to believe letting the question stand might help someone else down the road find the information they are looking for. It's more likely to confuse someone.